# Git IIS SSL "requested url returned error 500"

Tags: git, ssl, iis

I'm noob on these kink of configurations and need some help on one error that appears when I try to make the clone of a repositories.

I have an Windows Server 2012 with an IIS and I installed the Bonobo Git Server. Because I need some users to access from external I bought an SSL certificate and installed on the server.

When I access through web (https://./) I can access without any problems, the browser detects the SSL certificate, I can logon into Git Server.

But when I try to clone some repository through Git I always get this message "The requested URL returned error: 500".

I'ed already check all the configurations, permissions, everything, but I can't find out why the error always appears.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/20127449/6309 help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but isn't the solution. I already have a SSL certificate and the certificate is working fine. When I access to the Bonobo Git via browser I have everything working, I can check my SSL certificate correctly. The problem is, when I try to clone some repository (from internal or external network) I always receive the error "The requested URL returned error: 500". I think the problem is in some configuration on IIS.

Comment: Doesn't IIS log errors?

Comment: I'm sorry. How can I get the IIS logs?